# find number of clusters in hierarchical clustering dendrogram after cutree in r

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

Here I have some problem to find number of clusters after using cutree on a dendrogram. Here is my approach:

```
mat <- a huge matrix
hc <- (as.dist(mat), method = "average", members = NULL)  
#to cut the tree just 1 level below the maximum height
tree <- cutree(hc, h = hc$height[[length(hc$height)-1]])
```

By printing the tree variable I can see that my dendrogram is cut into two clusters. I can also get the labels from each cluster using names(tree[tree==1]), but how can get the number of clusters without looking at the data? I want to automate this in a pipeline based on number of clusters it has in tree variable.

Comment: length(unique(tree))?

Comment: i tried that one too, but it gives total number of labels it have.

Comment: I made it by running a loop over the tree, thanks .. :)

Answer (score 0):

finally i made it to answer my question by running a loop over the tree object after cutting dendrogram, but this might not be an optimal solution. and feel free to suggest modifications to make it more elegant..

```
clust <- c()
for (i in 1:length(tree)){
clust[i] <- tree[[i]]
}
length(unique(clust))
```

This should possibly give the answer as per my knowledge..
Thank you